# edit cell label in UICollectionView from keyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a label in each cell of my UICollectionView. Is it possible to edit the cell on runtime from the keyboard ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to make a UILabel editable would be a huge amount of work, and a waste of your time and effort.

If you want the user to be able to tap in a view, get a keyboard, and type text into the field, you should use a UITextField, not a label.

Create a custom collection cell that has a text field where you want it, and set the editable flag on the text field to YES. The OS will take care of the rest.

Comment: thanks a lot duncan. Actually, on my way back home - this behavior struck me and even i realized i might have to go for uitextfield.Thanks for confirming this approach .Now, I can go ahead with the change without any second thoughts.